# Showing $\frac{1}{z}$ is integrable on a specific set

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Consider $g: \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}, z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$. Take any $a \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. Then $g$ is integrable on $A:=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{z \in \mathbb{C}: z=at, t \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq}  \}$.

To show this, I would argue as follows:
First recall Cauchy's integral theorem for star-shaped domains:
If $G$ is a star-shaped domain with center $a$ and $g: G \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and holomorphic in $G\setminus\{a\}$, then $g$ integrated along any closed piecewise continuous differentiable path is zero.

By the equivalent characterisation of integrability, it suffices to show that $\int_{\phi} g \,dx = 0$ for any closed piecewise continuous differentiable path $\phi$.

To see this, note first that $A$ is star-shaped with center $-a$ and apply Cauchy's integral theorem for star-shaped domains.

> Can we prove this statement without Cauchy's integral theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is an open set. In general, if $g: A \to \mathbb{C}$ has a primitive function $G$, then $g$ is integrable on every contour $\gamma: [a,b] \to A$ with $\displaystyle \int_\gamma{g(z)\ dz} = G(\gamma(b)) - G(\gamma(a))$. Especially $\displaystyle \int_\gamma{g(z)\ dz} = 0$ if $\gamma$ is closed. So you could show that $g$ has a primitive function. In fact, what you are looking for is a branch of the complex logarithm:

Let $a = r \cdot \exp^{i\varphi}$, then 
\begin{equation*}
\exp: \{x + \mathrm{i}y: x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in (\varphi, \varphi + 2\pi) \} \to A \\
z = x + \mathrm{i}y \mapsto \exp(z) = \exp(x) \cdot \exp(\mathrm{i}y)
\end{equation*}

is bijective and the inverse function is the complex logarithm $\ln_{\varphi}(r \cdot \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}) := \ln(r) + t \cdot \mathrm{i}$, which is defined on $A$.
It follows just as in the real case that $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\ln_{\varphi} = \frac{1}{z}$ and $ln_{\varphi}$ is the primitive function of $g$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was helpful. I guess you have a little typo: $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$ should be $A$.

Comment: Edited it, thanks!